# Camera image picker and shake gesture?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimagepickercontroller, shake

Is it possible to detect a shake gesture when an `UIImagePickerController` is presented with `camera` source type? In such case, where/how should I implement it?

Comment: I would try subclassing and adding a gesture recognizer in an overridden viewDidLoad (remember to call super).  This class isn't really designed for subclassing, but simple things like this should work.  You should not muck with the views of the VC -- that is likely to have issues.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

A workaround is to make a custom image picker and then in that view controller implement the shake gesture.